# How was gravity explained in Ancient Greek and Roman times?

Tags: physics, ancient-greece, gravity, roman-empire

Gravity is of course something that we can all observe. Stuff falls towards the ground. But not everything: some things like steam or smoke defy this force and instead float up.

During Ancient Greek and Roman times (when the two shared a lot of culture and scientific knowledge), how was this natural force explained? What was believed to be the cause of gravity? And why was it that some things obeyed it while steam and smoke defied it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you think is missing from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_gravitational_theory#Antiquity)?

Comment: @sempaiscuba I was unaware that there was a Wikipedia article on this (although I shouldn't be surprised). I guess you could say that my Google/Wikipedia-foo failed me on that. An answer that includes the relevant information from there would address my question.

Comment: Thunderforge, you need to be a little cautious of Wikipedia articles. They're usually very good, but not always.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Aristotle's Natural Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-natphil/).

According to Aristotle, *change* in the natural world can be :

> [either] in accordance with the nature of the object — in which case the change is *natural* (*phusei*) or according to nature, or can happen in the face of a contrary disposition on the part of the nature of the entity — in which case the change is *forced* or contrary to nature.
>
> A mover can effect a motion which is contrary to its own nature. Aristotle’s example of such an unnatural mover is the lever, an object heavy by nature, with which loads can be lifted.
>
> [The] large class of natural motions [is formed by] the natural motions of the *elements*. [...] the elements move to their natural places — the light bodies up and the heavy ones down — by an appeal to their respective natures as causes (“that it is simply their nature to move somewhere, and this is what it is to be light and to be heavy,” *Physics* Book VIII, 255b13–17).

See Aristotle's text :

> > [[*Phys*, 255b](http://classics.mit.edu/Aristotle/physics.8.viii.html)] The activity of lightness consists in the light thing being in a certain place, namely high up: when it is in the contrary place, it is being prevented. The case is similar also in regard to quantity and quality. But, be it noted, this is the question we are trying to answer — how can we account for the motion of light things and heavy things to their proper places? The reason for it is that they have a natural tendency towards a certain position; and this is what it is to be light or heavy, the former being determined by an upward, the latter by a downward, tendency.

Comment: Interestingly (at least to me :-) ), this seems as much an explanation of density and buoyancy as it does the underlying force of gravity.

Answer (score 4):

The aristotelian theory affirmed that there was a natural 'affinity' between substances that were alike. Thus, a stone fell towards the ground because of a natural, telluric affinity, and fire/smoke rose to the sky because of a natural affinity, too...

Comment: Hi xxavier. This post could be much improved if you would back it up with some sources: Please include them in your post (and keep doing so in the future :) ).

Comment: True, thanks, but Mauro has already given good references. I wrote my answer just 'off the top'...  :)

Answer (score -1):

> How was gravity explained in Ancient Greek and Roman times?

It wasn't.

As xxavier and Mauro say, people like Aristotle claimed that things had a natural affinity or tendency towards a certain location. That's no explanation at all. *That's* what's missing from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_gravitational_theory#) sempaiscuba was referring to.

The Wikipedia article does include [a section on general relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_gravitational_theory#General_relativity) which purports to explain gravity. However it doesn't. Note this: *"Einstein proposed that spacetime is curved by matter, and that free-falling objects are moving along locally straight paths in curved spacetime".* He didn't, because:

Spacetime curvature is associated with the *tidal* force, not the force of gravity.

Spacetime models space at all times, so there's no motion through spacetime.

A concentration of energy causes spacetime curvature not just matter.

What Einstein did say is [this](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol7-trans/156?highlightText=%22spatially%20variable%22): *“As a simple geometric consideration shows, the curvature of light rays occurs only in spaces where the speed of light is spatially variable”.* Unfortunately you tend not to hear about this, which means gravity is generally not explained in modern times either.

> Gravity is of course something that we can all observe. Stuff falls towards the ground. But not everything: some things like steam or smoke defy this force and instead float up.

However they don't do this in a vacuum. Note that the Wikipedia [vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum) article says this: *"Vacuum has been a frequent topic of philosophical debate since ancient Greek times, but was not studied empirically until the 17th century".* The ancient Greeks weren't big on experiment.

Comment: I was more looking for "why is this a natural phenomenon", which I think that Aristotle's explanation is. Although it is indeed an incomplete explanation, it would probably have satisfied many of his day. Still, I'll upvote your answer since it does add some useful information.

Comment: So if Aristotle's theory, Einstein's theory and Newton's theory (I assume) did not explain gravity what *would* qualify as an explanation? Is there an example of a theory (of anything) that *does* explain what it describes?

Comment: Hi John Duffield. In this post, you don't seem to be adding anything to the previously existing answers, when it comes to the explanation of gravity in Antiquity. Thus, you post is essentially non-historical in nature. [hsm.se] is not the right place for such posts. Please improve your post to include some relevant historical information (not mentioned before by others), and remove the non-historical content.

Comment: @Danu: what I added was a crucial point - gravity was _not_ explained in antiquity. My further point was relevant because it concerned the Wikipedia article on the [history of gravitational theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_gravitational_theory#Antiquity). Sempaiscuba referred to this in a comment with 5 upvotes, but he was directing the OP to an article that was factually incorrect. My last point concerned vacuum and the way the Greeks didn't experiment much. That's relevant historical information which nobody else covered.

Comment: In fact, your assertion that "gravity was *not* explained in antiquity" is nothing but your assessment of the physical claims made in some ancient sources that had already been pointed out in other answers. Thus, this is not any historical contribution. Similarly, your assessment of the wikipedia page on the history of topic X is not relevant insofar it does not directly pertain to the historical content, but rather to the physical content. I stand by my earlier comment: Please remove the non-historical parts of your post and improve it so that it adds something to the already existing posts.

Comment: @Danu : gravity was _not_ explained in antiquity. That's a historical contribution of crucial relevance, and no other answers pointed this out. It isn't merely my assessment, as is clear from my reference to Einstein. My reference to the Wikipedia article is also crucial because other posters encouraged the OP to get his information from an incorrect source. That's not how stack exchange is supposed to function. My reference to the vacuum and experimentation is another historical contribution. So all in all I can't see how _any_ part of my post is not relevant to the OP or can be improved.